# How to clear an Image in a Userform?

Tags: image, excel, controls, userform, vba

I have a Userform in which I use an Image control. I display a picture in this control, based on two criteria.

I don't know how to clear this Image in the Userform when I want to type two new criteria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily *'clear'* your UserForm Image control (e.g. Image1) via `Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString)`. In the example below you would switch between showing a defined picture and displaying the empty control when clicking your command button. In order to control the Image status (empty or not) you check the image picture property via `If Image1.Picture Is Nothing Then`...

**Code example in userform module (Excel)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose: Change view between given image and no image
Dim sImgName As String                     ' picture name string
sImgName = "C:\Temp\MyPicture.gif""        ' <<< choose your picture name"
With Me.Image1
  If .Picture Is Nothing Then             ' picture property has been cleared already
     .Picture = LoadPicture(sImgName)
  Else                                    ' a picture is already displayed
     .Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString) ' clear it now
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

**Hint to use in MS Access**

Note the different use in MS Access repeating @DrMarbuse 's comment as late edit:

> In **Access 2010**, the picture is directly set by the image path. So LoadPicture() shall not be used anymore (In Excel it is required). *Everything stayed the same and worked like a charm.*

Comment: My problem is solved by your answer, thank you very much. One more thing, I see how many times you solved somebodies problem. How does that work ? How can I let you know you solved my problem ?

Comment: in access 2010, the picture is directly set by the image path. So `LoadPicture()` shall not be used anymore (In Excel it is required). Everything stayed the same and worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to see above code *working like a charm* and thanks for the additional info regarding Access 2010 (apart from Excel where `LoadPicture()` is required). - @DrMarbuse