# Removing image-controls in a UserForm using a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, controls, userform

I have created a UserForm which creates up to 6 image-controls and populates them with pictures when pressing a commandbutton
(via checkboxes you can select the pictures).

Now, when the pressing the commandbutton I want that all image-controls with their pictures are deleted before re-loading the image-controls and the pictures again, so that one does not have to `Unload` the UserForm when one wants to select other pictures via the checkboxes. I tried to do this by looping through the image controls, but this does not work with my code. Do you have any suggestions how I could solve this. Thank you.

(*Remember:* the whole idea is to do this deletion procedure as a first action in the sub; I don't want to `Unload Me` etc...)

```
Option Explicit
Dim i, k As Byte

Private Sub cmdGetGraphics_Click()
Dim sum_cb As Byte, cb_slct As Byte, y As Byte, sum_img As Byte
Dim Img As MSForms.Image
Dim Control As Control
Dim F(1 To 6) As Integer
Dim img_name As String

For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Control) = "Image" Then
        For i = 1 To 6
          Me.Controls.Remove "Image" & i 'error occurs here: Invalid Argument
        Next i
    End If
Next Control
```

Comment: `Me.Controls(Control).Remove` or possibly `Me.Controls.Remove(Control)`

Comment: @tom - Added syntax link (not corresponding to Nick's suggestion) and actually would appreciate your feedback, as anyone answering here invests some time to be helpful *(c.f. prior comment)*

Answer (score 0):

**I) What's behind the "Invalid argument" issue?**

I assume you created additional image controls leading to run time error "Invalid argument" - see case [2.2].

`[1]` As soon as you find the **first** *Image control* within the `For Each` loop, 
you remove already the complete set of "Image" & i controls within the `For i = 1 to 6` loop. 
It's important to know, that the `For Each` loop doesn't correct the original contents in `Me.Controls` by the current removals
and will try to analyze the whole collection (i.e. `Image2`, `Image3` etc. in the next steps).

**Case `[2.1]`** If your set of **"Image" & i controls** is restricted to these **6 elements only**, 
there wouldn't occur any run time error *"Invalid argument"* at all: 
A later `TypeName` check of `Image2` - which doesn't exist any more - results in an `Object` type instead of `Image` and 
thus prevents a further attempt to remove your six "Image" & i controls again.

**Case `[2.2]`** You created **additional image controls**: as soon as the `For Each` loop checks an additional image control, 
the `TypeName` test finds an `Image` type and attempts to remove the already deleted *six pack* again. 
=> Thus the control name doesn't exist, the argument actually is invalid.

**II. Conclusion**

In any case you should avoid to apply the `.Remove` method on already removed controls. 
For instance, it would be sufficient to use the following code once and for all:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    Me.Controls.Remove "Image" & i          ' property doesn't need brackets
Next i
```

IMO it would even be better, however to *rethink the coding logic* and **reuse the image controls** instead of *removing* them.
So you could easily empty their ► `.Picture` property by assigning a `LoadPicture(vbNullString)` value temporarily and reassign the chosen image names via `LoadPicture`as soon as you need them.
- C.f. [How to clear an imagage in a UserForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619363/how-to-clear-an-image-in-a-userform/47621909#47621909)

**Additional hints**

Your declaration line `Dim i, k As Byte` means that the not specified variable `i` is Variant by default. - 
So I'd suggest to say `Dim i As Long, k As Byte` (in VBA it's no memory advantage to declare  `As Integer`, 
especially regarding row or column counts exceeding the integer limitation; let aside API functions where Integers might be necessary)

It's not good use to make the current userform instance a self-destroying object in the Userform's code module itself via `Unload Me`.
For a deeper understanding I recommend reading the article ["UserForm1.Show?"](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

*Syntax* - see MS help [Remove method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/remove-method)